# subsequent calls to IntentService fault with NPE in run, but not debug

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-intentservice

My Activity is queuing work to an IntentService.  When i debug, the code seems to run ok.  when i run, i get the logcat results shown below.  i added a `thread.sleep(1000);`, but no change in behavior.  My assumption, based on the IntentService documentation is that if the IS is still active, it will queue the 2nd request and if it is inactive, it will restart.  Therefore, it's ok to issue back-to-back startService() requests without concern for timing or callbacks with status.

two different intents, bundles and arrays:

```
final int[] arSim1Config = new int[10];
arSim1Config[0] = 2;
arSim1Config[1] = 101;
arSim1Config[2] = (int)simStartTs;
arSim1Config[3] = simStopTs;
arSim1Config[4] = 20;
arSim1Config[5] = 70;
arSim1Config[6] = 40;
arSim1Config[7] = 8000;
arSim1Config[8] = 5000;
arSim1Config[9] = 17000;
// launch simulator threads using test parameters
Intent inStartSim = new Intent(this, SimService.class);
inStartSim.setAction("genData");
Bundle simBundle = new Bundle();
simBundle.putIntArray("simConfigAr",arSim1Config);
inStartSim.putExtras(simBundle);
startService(inStartSim);
final int[] arSim2Config = new int[10];
arSim2Config[0] = 2;
arSim2Config[1] = 102;
arSim2Config[2] = (int)simStartTs;
arSim2Config[3] = simStopTs;
arSim2Config[4] = 5;
arSim2Config[5] = 110;
arSim2Config[6] = 95;
arSim2Config[7] = 12000;
arSim2Config[8] = 5000;
rSim2Config[9] = 13000;
// launch simulator threads using test parameters
Intent inStartSim2 = new Intent(this, SimService.class);
inStartSim2.setAction("genData");
Bundle simBundle2 = new Bundle();
simBundle2.putIntArray("simConfigAr",arSim2Config);
inStartSim2.putExtras(simBundle2);
startService(inStartSim2);
```

logcat:

```
01-30 17:11:34.706    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-30 17:11:34.821    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-30 17:11:34.831    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
01-30 17:11:34.844    4075-4082/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/art﹕ Debugger is active
01-30 17:11:34.845    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
01-30 17:11:34.845    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.071    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.281    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.500    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.720    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.932    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.151    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.361    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.571    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.781    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.990    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:37.200    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:37.410    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:37.621    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1434)
01-30 17:11:37.979    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate() No saved state available
01-30 17:11:38.049    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-30 17:11:38.052    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6bdaf50, tid 4075
01-30 17:11:38.055    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
01-30 17:11:38.296    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa5f0a230, tid 4095
01-30 17:11:38.319    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-30 17:11:38.363    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-30 17:11:38.387    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:11:38.387    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5f2a460, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:11:38.451    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.02172712E9
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.02172717E9
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.02172722E9
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:11:54.971    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SimService]
Process: com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03, PID: 4075
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03.SimService.onHandleIntent(SimService.java:117)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
01-30 17:11:55.057    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 995 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-30 17:12:20.776    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate() No saved state available
01-30 17:12:20.905    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:12:20.905    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5f2a460, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:12:21.184    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:12:21.184    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5f9a9c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:16:55.107    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 4075 SIG: 9
01-30 17:16:55.732    4123-4123/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate() Restoring previous state
01-30 17:16:55.786    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-30 17:16:55.846    4123-4123/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c7d660, tid 4123
01-30 17:16:55.915    4123-4123/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
01-30 17:16:55.984    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c7d950, tid 4138
01-30 17:16:56.084    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-30 17:16:56.111    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-30 17:16:56.138    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:16:56.138    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6caccc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:16:56.471    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:16:56.472    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cacdc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:16:56.545    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:16:56.545    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.022045268E9
01-30 17:16:56.545    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.022045318E9
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.022045368E9
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:16:56.551    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SimService]
Process: com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03, PID: 4123
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03.SimService.onHandleIntent(SimService.java:117)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
01-30 17:21:56.621    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 4123 SIG: 9
01-30 17:11:34.706    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-30 17:11:34.821    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-30 17:11:34.831    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
01-30 17:11:34.844    4075-4082/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/art﹕ Debugger is active
01-30 17:11:34.845    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
01-30 17:11:34.845    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.071    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.281    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.500    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.720    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:35.932    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.151    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.361    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.571    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.781    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:36.990    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:37.200    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:37.410    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-30 17:11:37.621    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1434)
01-30 17:11:37.979    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate() No saved state available
01-30 17:11:38.049    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-30 17:11:38.052    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6bdaf50, tid 4075
01-30 17:11:38.055    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
01-30 17:11:38.296    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa5f0a230, tid 4095
01-30 17:11:38.319    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-30 17:11:38.363    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-30 17:11:38.387    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:11:38.387    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5f2a460, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:11:38.451    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.02172712E9
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.02172717E9
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.02172722E9
01-30 17:11:38.452    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:11:54.971    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SimService]
Process: com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03, PID: 4075
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03.SimService.onHandleIntent(SimService.java:117)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
01-30 17:11:55.057    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 995 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-30 17:12:20.776    4075-4075/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate() No saved state available
01-30 17:12:20.905    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:12:20.905    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5f2a460, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:12:21.184    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:12:21.184    4075-4095/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5f9a9c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:16:55.107    4075-4096/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 4075 SIG: 9
01-30 17:16:55.732    4123-4123/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/MainActivity﹕ onCreate() Restoring previous state
01-30 17:16:55.786    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-30 17:16:55.846    4123-4123/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c7d660, tid 4123
01-30 17:16:55.915    4123-4123/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
01-30 17:16:55.984    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c7d950, tid 4138
01-30 17:16:56.084    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-30 17:16:56.111    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-30 17:16:56.138    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:16:56.138    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6caccc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:16:56.471    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-30 17:16:56.472    4123-4138/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cacdc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-30 17:16:56.545    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:16:56.545    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.022045268E9
01-30 17:16:56.545    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.022045318E9
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/strmId val:﹕ 101.0
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/TS val:﹕ 1.022045368E9
01-30 17:16:56.546    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 D/ramp val:﹕ 70.0
01-30 17:16:56.551    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SimService]
Process: com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03, PID: 4123
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03.SimService.onHandleIntent(SimService.java:117)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
01-30 17:21:56.621    4123-4140/com.smartmedtek.prj.smartmed03 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 4123 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I moved the `Thread.sleep(1000);` from the IntentService to the Activity between the `startService(inStartSimx);` code and it seems to run.  Still seeing some unexpected behaviors.  Based on the IntentService docs, this should not be necessary.  Comment if you have seen similar problems even if you don't have a solution.

Comment: startService(inStartSim);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final int[] arSim2Config = new int[10];

Comment: UPDATE: code was calling sequential Activity classes to launch the IntentService.  a bug in one was issuing multiple onCreate() AND the "run" was not loading the current code into the emulator (another issue for another thread).  this could (likely) account for the NPE in "run" and not "debug" modes.